# How to initialize argv[i]?

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize argv[i] to the value of "C:\Games\World_of_Tanks\res\packages\gui.pkg" with a const char* pointer. Can I get some help doing this as I am new to programming.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

void pf(const char* name)
{
        HANDLE file = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
        if(file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { printf("couldn't open %s\n", name); return; };

    unsigned int len  = GetFileSize(file, 0);

    HANDLE mapping  = CreateFileMapping(file, 0, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, 0);
    if(mapping == 0) { printf("couldn't map %s\n", name); return; }

    const char* data = (const char*) MapViewOfFile(mapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

    if(data)
    {
        printf("prefetching %s... ", name);

        // need volatile or need to use result - compiler will otherwise optimize out whole     loop
        volatile unsigned int touch = 0;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i += 4096)
            touch += data[i];
    }
    else
        printf("couldn't create view of %s\n", name);

    UnmapViewOfFile(data);
    CloseHandle(mapping);
    CloseHandle(file);
}

    int main(int argc, const char** argv)
    {

        if(argc >= 2) for(int i = 1; argv[i]; ++i) pf(argv[i]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Normally `argv` is set through the program's invocation, so if you wanted to set `argv[1]` to `test`, you'd run the program like `myprogram.exe test`.

Comment: This may be an XY Problem...

Comment: The code shown seems to simply use `argv` values but no change is needed to `argv`. What happens is that when later using the files there will be (hopefully) no random wait for disk access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of a `const char`can not be changed. What is it you want to do?

If you want a value of the argv array in the main function to be set you need to execute the program with a command line argument like:

```
program argument argument etc
```

Edit from comment info:

If you want to run the `pf`function on program start you could add

```
pf("C:\Games\World_of_Tanks\res\packages\gui.pkg"); // this might need to be escaped...
```

in the main function.

Comment: I want to prefetch a file, there is a void function also in the program, however I did not include it in the original code as it did not concern it, I will update it now.

Comment: "prefetch"? Are you trying to get the file to download?

Comment: I am trying to force windows to cache the file to ram

Comment: Wow. You can do that just by opening it.

Comment: lol, I know, its a game GUI file that I would like to cache to ram before opening the game to speed up load times

Answer (score 0):

You can just use another array

```
const char *myargv[] = { "pgmname",
                         "my_first_filename.dat",
                         "my_second_filename.dat",
                         NULL };
argv = myargv;
argc = 3;
```

If this is just to be able to run the program from an IDE note however that there is for sure a GUI option for setting the command line arguments for the program.

Comment: I think you would need to put argv = myargv and argc = 3 before the array as c++ reads from top to bottom. I am new to c++ what do you place under pgname?

Comment: `pgmname` is the name of the program, but it's not really clear in the standard what this name really should be (the full path? just the name? what about a file that doesn't have a name?). You should use `argv[0]` just when logging error messages, but any other use may work or not (for example you cannot assume that calling `fopen` on it will work). In the example I'm re-assigning the current value of `argv` and `argc` and the sequence is correct as shown.